# R package installation error: no package called ‘org.Hs.eg.db’

Tags: r

I am trying to install this package http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/data/annotation/html/org.Hs.eg.db.html. When I try to load org.Hs.eg.db using `library (org.Hs.eg.db)` , gives me this

```
error: Error in library(org.Hs.eg.db) : 
  there is no package called ‘org.Hs.eg.db’
```

It says the packages are downloaded here:

```
The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmpgy1ZJE/downloaded_packages’
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Did you install it using the `biocLite()` tool from BioConductor? https://www.bioconductor.org/install/

Comment: Yes, I used `biocLite()`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. `library(org.Hs.eg.db)` works for me, after `source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R"); biocLite("org.Hs.eg.db")`.

Comment: Here is the full error: `Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'org.Hs.eg.db', details:
  call: ls(ann_objs)
  error: 2 arguments passed to .Internal(ls) which requires 3
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/mycomp/R_latest/lib/R/library/org.Hs.eg.db’`

Comment: What is your version of R? What is your version of Bioconductor? Mine are `3.2.2` and `3.2`, respectively. You maybe need to perform some `biocLite()`.

Comment: Thanks, it was a simple fix. `biocLite()` did work.

Answer (score 1):

If you run into this error nowadays you have to install the package using

```
BiocManager::install("org.Hs.eg.db")
```